# 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'is_initialized' when using tensorflow.keras.backend.shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a keras model which works fine when I import submodules (layers, backend functions) from keras. However, the same exact model breaks if I import those from tensorflow.keras.

Here is an example that illustrates the issue:

```
if True:
  from keras import backend as K
  from keras.models import Model
  from keras.layers import Input, Lambda
  from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
else:
  from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
  from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
  from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Lambda
  from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator 

def ex_add(inputs):
  """Made-up example that illustrates the problem"""
  ones = K.ones(K.shape(inputs))
  return inputs + ones

img_input = Input(shape=(512, 512, 3))

ex = Lambda(pconv_add)(img_input)    

model = Model(inputs=[img_input], outputs=ex)
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mse')

test_generator = ... # data_generator.flow_from_directory() using ImageDataGenerator
img = next(test_generator)[0]
pconv_predict = model.predict(img)
```

When importing from keras, everything works fine. Importing from tensorflow.keras leads to this (when I call model.predict or model.fit_generator):

> ERROR:tensorflow:================================== Object was never
>   used (type ):
>    If you want
>   to mark it as used call its "mark_used()" method. It was originally
>   created here:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in
>   _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)
>
> ...
>
> (long message removed fro brevity)
>
> ...
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        14 #model.summary()
>        15 img = next(train_generator)[0][0]
>   ---> 16 pconv_predict = model.predict(img)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py
>   in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, max_queue_size,
>   workers, use_multiprocessing)    1876     else:    1877       return
>   training_arrays.predict_loop(
>   -> 1878           self, x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose, steps=steps)    1879     1880   def train_on_batch(self, x, y=None,
>   sample_weight=None, class_weight=None):
>
> ...
>
> (long message removed fro brevity)
>
> ...
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py
>   in is_variable_initialized(variable)    2897     initialized, `False`
>   otherwise.    2898   """
>   -> 2899   return state_ops.is_variable_initialized(variable)    2900     2901
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/state_ops.py
>   in is_variable_initialized(ref, name)
>       129     return gen_state_ops.is_variable_initialized(ref=ref, name=name)
>       130   # Handle resource variables.
>   --> 131   return ref.is_initialized(name=name)
>       132 
>       133
>
> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'is_initialized'

The problem roots in the Lambda layer and particularly in the K.shape(inputs). I tried replacing it with (4, 512, 512, 3) and it worked fine regardless of the way I import keras. Have you seen this problem before and how can I solve it?

Note, I run this code on Colaboratory. The keras and tensorflow.keras versions are 
2.2.4 and 2.1.6-tf.

Answer (score 2):

It is an open issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24938 and is only in graph mode. In eager mode this may work. However, usage of tf.zeros work fine in both graph and eager mode.